# How to test X509TrustManager subclass?

Tags: java, ssl, junit, cryptography, x509certificate

I subclassed `javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager` so I could use a private SSL cert. Now I am trying to write a JUnit test for my class, but the test cases keep giving me a null pointer exception.

*E.g.* my implementation of `checkClientTrusted()` is an empty method.  However, when I call that method with a (supposedly) valid instance of `X509Certificate[]` (and any sort of String for that matter), JUnit reports a `NullException` at that line of test code.  Any suggestions as to what I am missing?

Comment: Your empty implementation of checkClientTrusted() is insecure. Don't do this.

Comment: @EJP - actually no, it is not insecure for my app.  I don't have the time to go into details, but for what I am doing, this being an empty is not a problem.

Comment: RFC 2246 doesn't agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I subclassed my test class from `junit.framework.TestCase`, which caused my `@BeforeClass` setup method not to get called (and therefore the variables I instantiated there were still null).  After deleting that, things are working now.

Answer (score 7):

Subclassing 'X509TrustManager' just for the use of a self signed certificate (I assume thats what you mean with 'private SSL cert' ?) is a bit overkill. Easier ways to use such a certificate are:

Use a keystore file (truststore) with the certificate (or the certificate of the CA with which you created your self signed certificate) and point your application to that. All you have to do is make sure the 'SSLContext' knows about your truststore. Take a look at the (really well written) article  [Custom SSL for advanced JSSE developers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-customssl/#8) for details. Technically this is even safer then using the global JRE truststore since only your certificate will be accepted as valid.

Add the certificate (or the certificate of the CA with which you created your self signed certificate) to the global truststore of the JRE with 'keytool'. The global JRE truststore is located in '$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts'. The password of the JRE truststore is always 'changeit'. Although this way obviously makes deployment harder, since sometimes you don't control the JRE installation.

Comment: Note that the certificate in the truststore should be marked `trusted`. Just out of completeness, `keytool` will probably ask to make it trusted anywho. Oh, en hoi :)

Comment: The users of my app can barely get this private app installed from an email attachment (this is in an Android app), let alone put a new cert on their phones.  My app is very secure as is.

I really do just need assistance with the JUnit testing, not help with my implementation here.

Comment: You would distribute the trust/key store as part of your application (you could even embed it in the JAR file) and not have users themselves install the certificate. While it will work I don't think subclassing 'X509TrustManager' the way you do should be encouraged. 'X509TrustManager' implementations should be used to perform additional checks on the certificate like checking its status with OCSP. @owlstead gegroet! :-)

Comment: It looks like IBM's webmaster broke the link to the article to "Custom SSL for advanced JSSE developers". Webmasters are about as useful as politicians.

Comment: @jww They even broke it for their own support docs: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21191941 . I can't find the original article anymore. Which is really a shame because it was well written.